# how to hide mat expansion panel header when in expanded mode

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have multiple mat expansion panels on a page i want that when i expand a panel its header show hide.

**HTML**

```
<mat-expansion-panel 
  class="z-depth-5" 
  (opened)="panelOpenState = true" 
  (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header 
    [collapsedHeight]="customCollapsedHeight"       
    [expandedHeight]="customExpandedHeight">
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

**CSS**

```
.mat-expansion-panel.mat-expanded {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0px;
  left: 60px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use *ngIf directive in your mat-expansion-panel-header.

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header *ngIf="!panelOpenState 
[collapsedHeight]="customCollapsedHeight" [expandedHeight]="customExpandedHeight">
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

Answer (score 2):

[**`mat-expansion-panel`**](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api#MatExpansionPanel) has `opened` and `closed` `@Output()` properties that you can use to track which item is currently opened in the template. You're already using them.

To these methods, you can pass in the `index` of the currently openend/closed item in the accordion list.

With this, you can set a property in your Component to track just that.

In case of `opened` set that property. In the case of `closed`, check if the item index that was currently clicked is equal to the set index on the class. If so reset the class property to -1.

---

In code, this will translate to:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class ExpansionOverviewExample {
  currentlyOpenedItemIndex = -1;

  items = [...];

  setOpened(itemIndex) {
    this.currentlyOpenedItemIndex = itemIndex;
  }

  setClosed(itemIndex) {
    if(this.currentlyOpenedItemIndex === itemIndex) {
      this.currentlyOpenedItemIndex = -1;
    }
  }

}
```

---

In the template, you can have something like this:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel 
    *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;"
    (opened)="setOpened(i)"
    (closed)="setClosed(i)">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        {{ item.header }}
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        {{ item.description }} | {{ currentlyOpenedItemIndex === i ? 'Close' : 'Open' }}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>{{ item.content }}</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-expansion-panel-toggle-header?file=app/expansion-overview-example.html) for your ref.